# Actualización masiva con AJAX (Async NO)

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

En una pagina web, recibo alrededor de 400.000 registros (EXCEL), muestro estos registros en pantalla, el usuario los verifica para confirmar su carga, entonces, debo actualizarlo en una base de datos.

Para ello voy tomando cada 100 registros, los envío a la base de datos con AJAX en modo sincrono (**async:false**), y deseo ir mostrando el avance en cada envío (actualizando el contenido de un elemento **div**), esto lo hace, pero no es sino hasta el final que lo muestra en pantalla (no muestra resultados intermedios).

Deseo mostrar resultados intermedios para que el usuario, en su espera de aproximada de 5 minutos vaya observando el avance.

Comment: El usuario revisa 400 mil registros antes de cargarlos??

Comment: El modo `async` en `true` puede estar previniendo que se renderice correctamente la página. Usalo en `true` junto con `await`.

Comment: si es sincronico, NADA se va a actualizar, porque esta todo ocupado con eso... igual nade, y te lo digo por experiencia, revisa 400000 registros, de nada...

Comment: Este es el típico caso de que a causa de una falencia técnica se adopta una mala solución. Primero, hoy por hoy no hay ninguna escusa para no usa funciones `async` que con eso se soluciona tu problema y no hay mas vueltas; y segundo, que cargar 400 mil registros de un excel a una web y de la web a la base de datos me parece que no es la mejor de la soluciones posibles

Comment: Revisar puede significar que se hagan cálculos, se muestren subtotales, etc... No haga juicio de la implementación... Simplemente no respondas si no se tiene la respuesta.  Gracias

Comment: Yo creo que se te puede sugerir soluciones responsables o soluciones que no critiquen la implementación. Lamentablemente no tengo ninguna que cumpla con ambos requisitos.